# ¿Cómo y cuando añadir protección de CSRF en php?

Tags: php

En mi página tengo muchas ejecuciones y algunas son de tipo formularios en los que sé que se necesita un token de CSRF, pero no estoy seguro de que si tengo que generarlo todas las veces que el formulario sea enviado ó puedo generar uno de la sesión y utilizarlo en todos los procesos que el usuario registrado realice.

Y qué pasa cuando creo un simple hiperenlace tipo: `www.ejemplo.com/index.php?id=40` y al pulsarlo redirigo a una página donde el usuario tiene un `$_GET['id']`, también necesito utilizar el CSRF token? En caso afirmativo, también vale el de la sesión?

Para generarlo dentro de la sesión el método más seguro que he encontrado es el siguiente:

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['token'])) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
}
$token = $_SESSION['token'];
```

Pero si no se utiliza el token de sesión, cómo iniciarlo? ¿O solamente existen los CRFS de sesión? Digo porque en Laravel he visto que para cada acción de formulario realizada se utilizaba un token diferente, pero en PHP a pelo no he visto diferentes tokens que a los de la sesión. Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay que añadirlo en todos los formularios, con un token diferente cada vez; de lo contrario no tiene sentido.

No almacenes una única variable `$_SESSION['token']` por session, sino una variable `$_SESSION['token_'.$token_string]` por cada formulario servido, cada una con el valor igual al timestamp de creación.

```
$token_string = cualquier_forma_de_generar_el_token();
$_SESSION['token_'.$token_string] = time();
```

Cuando el usuario envíe el formulario al servidor, comprueba que la variable `token_<variable 'csrf' de $_POST>` existe en la sesión. Si no existe o han pasado más de x minutos (cualquier tiempo que consideres óptimo para tu aplicación), devuelve error.

```
$max_minutos_csrf = 60;
$token_string = limpia_pule_y_da_esplendor($_POST['csrf']);
if ( !isset($_SESSION['token_'.$token_string] ||
     $_SESSION['token_'.$token_string] < time() - $max_minutos_csrf * 60 * 1000 ) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    exit('Error de CSRF.');
}
```

Te recomiendo que no intentes reinventar la rueda y utilices alguna librería:

- https://github.com/Riimu/Kit-CSRF
- https://github.com/mebjas/CSRF-Protector-PHP

Hay muchas más. Google es tu amigo :)

En respuesta a tu comentario sobre cómo añadir el campo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<?php echo htmlentities($string_de_token); ?>" />
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta !

Comment: como poner en el `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $string_de_token"; ?>/>` ?

Comment: Me devuelve `Undefined index: token_1491237675`

Comment: Tendrás que debuguear. Asegúrate de iniciar la sesión con `session_start()`, vuelca el contenido de `$_SESSION`, etc... Pero, en serio, utiliza una librería.

Comment: Yo no utilizo framework, lo hago todo a pelo... Puedo utilizar esas librerias sin utilizar framework ? @jotaelesalinas He intentado instalar una libreria pero carece de documentacion, nose como utilizarlo, me da errores y errores y luego para hacer el deployment mi servidor me dara mas errores si quiero utilizar el composer ahi.... estoy perdido

Comment: Hola @Lukas. Sí, puedes usar las librerías sin utilizar un framework. Normalmente necesitarás `composer`, que es una maravilla y yo ahora no sé cómo podía vivir antes sin él. Eso sí, evita librerías sin buena documentación. ¿Sigues con el error "undefined index"?

Comment: Sii @jotaelesalinas acabo de publicar una nueva pregunta para resolver el problema http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/60376/c%C3%B3mo-implementar-csfr-token-en-tipo-string

Comment: Tienes que poner `$token_string` en el input hidden, no `$token`.