# ¿Cómo implementar CSFR token en tipo string?

Tags: php

Tengo el código para iniciar el token:

```
session_start();

$token_string = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
$_SESSION['token_'.$token_string] = time();

$token = $_SESSION['token_'.$token_string] = time();
```

El código para poner un escondido input en mi formulario

```
<form ... >

    <?php
          echo '<input type="hidden" name="token" value="'.$token.'" />';
     ?>
    ...

</form>
```

Y el código para ver si el token ha sido recibido correctamente:

```
$max_minutos_csrf = 60;

    $token_string = $_POST['token'];
    if ( !isset($_SESSION['token_'.$token_string]) ||
         $_SESSION['token_'.$token_string] < time() - $max_minutos_csrf * 1000 ) {

        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
        exit('Error de CSRF.');

    } else {

        // Ejecutar el resto de Php Mysql
    }
```

Me devuelve este error:

> Notice: Undefined index: token_1491320450

Si hago `echo $_POST['token']` me da esto: 1491320450

Si hago `var_dump($_SESSION)` me da:

```
array (size=7)
  'user_session' => string '9' (length=1)
  'token_f31339250d26b0e4af79749a6ecc56f2e7e1777b41d62b7472174b10443426fc' => int 1491322443
  'token_7c65f80f5fb3d47d00b4480580edcbc7a60694018309f50f413bad16ed2634af' => int 1491322444
  'token_87f9a9bfb2397f5c4b5b0865e3fcc513163a446bcb6cd47d8ac112e66f813b8b' => int 1491322445
  'token_8ca703ee6144b88fc7df80ac46a669d109636f1a94acddb1a3db43a6c841382d' => int 1491322446
  'token_082860bf9f77bfb159e97b0a8e17bfb71bf6bfc804e2bdf1572b45991424c0e3' => int 1491322699
  'token_e4999ec00c11f9311f0778c38bfbfe8887a82907e386830d747af17be0b88ee2' => int 1491322700
```

Comment: Sii @MarcosGallardo, la sesion del usuario esta definida en `sessions.php` y esta incluida en el archivo donde recibo el `POST`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partiendo de que la función [`time`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.time.php) devuelve el tiempo en `segundos`.

### Errores:

- En la variable `$max_minutos_csrf`, como el nombre lo dice, se espera que esté en `minutos` y al multiplicarla por `1000`, se obtiene `60.000 segundos`, que serían, `1.000 minutos` o `16.666 horas`.
- En la variable `$token` estas guardando el `tiempo` y no el `token_string` que es lo que necesitas para saber si existe en `$_SESSION`.

### Soluciones:

- Multiplicar `$max_minutos_csrf` por `60 (segs)` para que el valor esté en `minutos`.
- `Undefined index: token_1491320450`, puede deberse a:

  1. No has iniciado sesión (`eg: session_start();`).
  2. Se venció la sesión. Puedes aumentar el tiempo de vida de la sesión con la función [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)
  3. Realmente no existe el valor en `$_SESSION`.

     En tu caso es la opción `3`, para solucionarlo deberías imprimir en el `value` del `input` el `$token_string`.

Ejemplo:

**PHP:**

```
// Aumentar tiempo de vida de la sesion
$lifetime = 60 * 60; // 1 hora
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
session_start();

// Validar CSRF
$max_minutos_csrf = 60 * 60; // 1 hora

$token_string = $_POST['token'];
if ( !isset($_SESSION['token_'.$token_string]) ||
     $_SESSION['token_'.$token_string] < (time() - $max_minutos_csrf)) {

    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    exit('Error de CSRF.');

} else {

    // Ejecutar el resto de Php Mysql
}
```

**HTML**

```
 <form..>
 <?php
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="token" value="'.$token_string.'" />';
 ?>
 </form>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ha sido útil pero me sigue sin resolver el problema. Cuando lo ejecuto me sigue metiendo el error `Notice: Undefined index: token_1491322445 ` y si hago `echo $_POST['token']` me devuelve esto: 1491322445

Comment: He hecho `var_dump($_SESSION)` Marcos

Comment: eso espero :DDD muchas gracias

Comment: @MarcoGallardo Gracias Marco, no me da el error de Undefined index, pero me devuelve esto: `Error de CSRF` - esto es lo que esta en la variable `$_POST['token']`: 9f69b442c6f33e12a15105279a8957a129acc9eaef43e80bd892299e2f68fb14 y esto es lo que esta en `$_SESSION['token_'.$token_string]` 1491323328

Comment: Hola @MarcosGallardo este es el resultado: `Error de CSRF.1491376843 > 1491373244`.

Comment: creo que he encontrado el error, deberia ser `if ( !isset($_SESSION['token_'.$token_string]) ||
     $_SESSION['token_'.$token_string] > (time() + $max_minutos_csrf))` `+` en vez de `-` porque lo que queremos es que el token el de ahora + una hora para dar el error ! Eureka

Comment: @Lukas, estaba bien la condición usando el operador menor (`<`) (_en algún lugar de mi cabeza se me cruzó un cable_). Ejemplo: si creamos el `token` a las `10:00` y la hora actual es `10:30` y le restamos `1hr`, quiere decir que serian las `09:30`, es decir, está mal, porque las `10:00` (hora del `token`) es mayor a `09:30` (hora actual menos una hora), el `token` aún no se venció.